# Struggling with footer and modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling with the footer when the modal pops up. The footer doesn't get the opacity that the rest of the HTML page gets. There's anyway to fix it?

PS: It may not be clear in the snippet, so here's the image of the problem: [image]

Codes:

```js
/*Abre e fecha o modal*/

const Modal = {
  open(){
    document.querySelector('.modal-overlay').classList.toggle('active')             
  }
}

const transactions = [
  {
      id: 1,
      description: 'Luz',
      amount: -50000,
      date: '23/01/2021'
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      description: 'Website',
      amount: 500000,
      date: '23/01/2021'
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      description: 'Internet',
      amount: -2000,
      date: '23/01/2021'
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      description: 'App',
      amount: 2000,
      date: '23/01/2021'
  },
]


//transaçoes

const Transaction = {
  entry(){
    //grana que entra
    
  },
  out(){
    //grana que subtrai

  },
  total(){
    //entry - out

  }
}



/* const Modal = {
  open(){
    document.querySelector('.modal-overlay').classList.add('active')
  },
  close(){
    document.querySelector('.modal-overlay').classList.remove('')
  }
}
*/


//criando o HTML pelo JavaScript



const DOM = {
  transactionsCointainer: document.querySelector('#data-table tbody'),
  addTransaction(transaction, index){
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.innerHTML = DOM.innerHTMLTransaction(transaction)

    DOM.transactionsCointainer.appendChild(tr)

    console.log(tr.innerHTML)

  },


  innerHTMLTransaction(transaction) {
    const CSSclass = transaction.amount> 0 ? "income" : "expense"  

    const amount =  Utils.formatCurrency(transaction.amount)

    const html = 
    `
        <td class="description">${transaction.description}</td>
        <td class="${CSSclass}">${amount}</td>
        <td class="date">${transaction.date}</td>
        <td>
          <img src="/assets/minus.svg" alt="Remover Transação">
        </td>
    `

    return html
  }
}


const Utils = {
  formatCurrency(value){
    const signal = Number(value) < 0 ? "-" :  ""

    value = String(value).replace(/\D/g, "")

    value = Number(value) / 100

    value = value.toLocaleString("pt-br", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "BRL"
    })

    return signal + value
  }
    
}

transactions.forEach(function(transaction){
  DOM.addTransaction(transaction)
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap');

:root {
  --color-dark       : #363f5f;
  --color-green      : #2D4A22;
  --color-light-green: #49aa26;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin : 0;
  border : 0;
}

body {
  font-family     : 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
}

html {
  font-size: 93.75%;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}

.container {
  width : min(90vw, 800px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* === HEADER === */

header {
  background: var(--color-green);
  padding   : 2rem 0 10rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  color      : #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

/*=== TITLES === */

h2{
  margin-top   : 3.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
  color        : var(--color-dark);
  font-weight  : normal;
}

/*=== BALANCE === */

#balance {
  margin-top: -8rem;
}

#balance h2 {
  color      : white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*=== CARDS === */

.card {
  background   : white;
  padding      : 1.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size  : 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card p {
  font-size  : 2rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  margin-top : 1rem;
}

.card.total {
  background: var(--color-light-green);
  color     : white;
}


/* === TRANSAÇÕES === */

#transaction {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}


#data-table {
  width         : 100%;
  border-spacing: 0 0.5rem;
}

table thead tr th:first-child,
table tbody tr td:first-child{
  border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem;
}

table thead tr th:last-child,
table tbody tr td:last-child{
  border-radius: 0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
}

table th {
  color           : #969CB3;
  font-weight     : normal;
  padding         : 1rem 2rem;
  text-align      : left;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius   : 0.25rem;
  font-weight     : bold;
}


td.description {
  color: var(--color-dark);
}

td.income {
  color: #12a454;
}

td.expense {
  color: rgb(228, 67, 67);
}

td.date {
  color: var(--color-dark);
}

table td {
  background : white;
  padding    : 1rem 2rem;
  color      : #969CB3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table tbody tr {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

table tbody tr:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--color-light-green);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

button:hover {
    background: rgb(0, 140, 0);
}

.button-new {
  color: var(--color-light-green);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: .8rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

a .button {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.button-new:hover {
  color: #06bd4c;
  transition: color 700ms;
}

td img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* === MODAL === */
.modal-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.modal-overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal {
  background: #f0f2f5;
  padding: 2.4rem ;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 90%;
  
}

/*=== MODAL FORM === */

#form {
  max-width: 500px;
}

#form h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

input {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.8rem;
}

.input-group {
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}

.input-group small {
  opacity: .4;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*=== MODAL BUTTON === */

.input-group-actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1.8rem;
}

.input-group-actions .button,
.input-group.actions button {
  width: 48%;
}

.input-group-actions .button {
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #FF4136;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #FF4136;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.input-group-actions .button:hover {
    background: rgb(143, 0, 0);
}

/* === FOOTER === */

footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
   
}

/* === RESPONSIVE === */

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html { font-size: 87.5%;
}

#balance {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
}
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    footer{
        display: block;
        background-color: var(--color-green);
        color: #fff;
        padding: 2rem 0 10rem;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>dev.finance$</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="/assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo Dev Finance">
    </header>

    <main class="container">
        <section id="balance">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Balanço</h2>


            <div class="card">
                <h3>
                    <span>Entradas</span>
                    <img src="/assets/income.svg" alt="Imagem de Entradas">
                </h3>
                <p>R$ 5.000,00</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <h3>
                    <span>Saídas</span>
                    <img src="/assets/expense.svg" alt="Imagem de Saídas">
                </h3>
                <p>R$ 2.000,00</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card total">
                <h3>
                    <span>Total</span>
                    <img src="/assets/total.svg" alt="Imagem de Total">
                </h3>
                <p>R$ 3.000,00</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="transaction">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Transações</h2>

            <a href="#" onclick="Modal.open()" class="button-new">+ Nova Transação</a>
            <table id="data-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Descrição</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>

    <div class="modal-overlay">
        <div class="modal">
            <div id="form">
                <h2>Nova Transação</h2>
                <form action="">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="description">Descrição</label>
                        <input type="text" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Descrição">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="amount">Valor</label>
                        <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="0,00" step="0.01">
                        <small>Usar o sinal - (negativo) para despesas e , (vírgula) para casas decimais.</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="date">Data</label>
                        <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group-actions">
                        <a href="" class="button">Cancelar</a>
                        <button>Salvar</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <img src="/assets/logo-footer.svg" alt="Logo Dev Finance">
    </footer>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `modal-overlay` is displaying behind your footer.

Add a `z-index: 1000` to your modal-overlay rule.

```css
.modal-overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1000;  /* <- add this */
}
```